# Hibernate 5.x migration Criteria to CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table modeled in a legacy .hbm.xml file.

The legacy code to retrieve a row uses an org.hibernate.Criteria to get a uniqueResult(). In migrating to Hibernate 5.x, Criteria is deprecated so I am trying to use CriteriaBuilder to achieve the same. However when I try to add restrictions (Hib 5.x) based on what worked previously (Hib 4.x) I get an IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [xyzKey.plantName] on this ManagedType [com.foo.bar.Plant]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:147)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:118)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:43)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateAttributeInternal(AbstractFromImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:204)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:177)
```

Plant.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class lazy="false" name="com.foo.bar.Plant" table="Plant">
        <meta inherit="false" attribute="extends">com.foo.bar.PlantBase</meta>

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="plantID" unsaved-value="null">
            <meta inherit="false" attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <component name="xyzKey" class="com.foo.bar.PlantKey">
            <meta inherit="false" attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
            <property name="plantName" type="string" index="xyzKeyndx" unique-key="plantKey">
                <column name="plantName" />
            </property>
            <property name="xyzRevision" type="string" index="xyzKeyndx" unique-key="plantKey">
                <column name="xyzRevision" length="100"/>
            </property>
        </component>

        <property name="active" type="java.lang.Boolean" index="xyzKeyndx">
            <column name="active"  not-null="true"/>
        </property>

        <property name="description" type="string" not-null="false">
            <meta inherit="false" attribute="field-description">User specified description. Does not need to be unique.</meta>
            <meta inherit="false" attribute="use-in-tostring">false</meta>
            <column name="descr" not-null="false" />
        </property>

        <property name="location" type="string" not-null="true">
            <column name="location" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate 4.x based code that works:

```
protected Plant selectPlant(Session session, PlantKey xyzKey)
{
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Plant.class);
    if (Util.isEmpty(xyzKey.getXyzRevision()))
    {
        SimpleExpression plantName = Restrictions.eq("xyzKey.plantName", xyzKey.getPlantName());
        SimpleExpression active = Restrictions.eq("active", true);
        c.add(Restrictions.and(plantName, active));
    }
    else
    {
        c.add( Restrictions.eq("xyzKey", xyzKey) );
    }
    Plant plant = (Plant)c.uniqueResult();
    return plant;
}
```

Hibernate 5.x based code that fails:

```
protected Plant selectPlant(Session session, PlantKey xyzKey)
{
    ElapsedTimer timer = new ElapsedTimer();

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Plant> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Plant.class);
    Root<Plant> root = criteriaQuery.from(Plant.class);

    List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
    if ( FBCUtil.isEmpty(vpeKey.getVpeRevision()) )
    {
        restrictions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("xyzKey.plantName"), xyzKey.getPlantName())); // FAILS HERE!
        restrictions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("active"), true));
    }
    else
    {
        restrictions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("xyzKey"), xyzKey));
    }

    criteriaQuery.where(restrictions.toArray(new Predicate[restrictions.size()]));

    Query<Plant> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    Plant plant = query.uniqueResult();

    return plant;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("xyzKey").get("plantName"), xyzKey.getPlantName())
```